# Store in firestorage and keep url in variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am a beginner in Javascript.

All I want to do is to store a file in Firestorage, and then keep the URL link in a variable.
However, right now, the URL is not kept, and my variable is empty.

```
const pictureUrl = ''

// Upload picture part
   var refname = 'profile_pictures/' + "Picture" + "_" + "Name";
   let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(refname);
   let firstFile = document.getElementById("pictureImported").files[0]
   let uploadTask = storageRef.put(firstFile).then(function(fileSnapshot) {
   fileSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => pictureUrl = url)
})

console.log(pictureUrl);
```

The console.log gives a blank line. What should I do to really save the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pictureUrl` will only have a value inside the `then()` since `getDownloadUrl()` is asynchronous. If you want to the `pictureUrl` outside the `then()` method then do the following:

```
function storeImage(firstFile){
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let uploadTask = storageRef.put(firstFile).then((fileSnapshot)=> {
   fileSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(url => {
   pictureUrl = url;
   resolve(pictureUrl);
     });
   });
}
```

Then to access the `url` you can do:

```
storageImage(file).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Check here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: So to access the result, I need an other Promise? Not very convenient. The idea is to repeat the storage for three files, and then store the three urls in a firestore collection. Thus, I want to avoid new promises

Comment: This is the only way since the API is asynchronous meaning the `pictureUrl` outside the `then()` will not give you any value. All I/O operation using any framework are going to be asynchronous . If you have more than one promise, then you can use `Promise.all()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Ok I get it. But is there a way to store the value from storageImage() outside of the then() ? Because right now, Im doing the way you suggest, but the result remains the same. storageImage is not async right? So it should be possible?

Comment: it is asynchronous since it returns a promise. You can use `async` and `await` but again the same logic is applied https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function